# How to set a default configuration for simulator build?

Tags: ios, xcode, configuration

As you know when you create a new Xcode project you have two configuration already created for you: `Debug` and `Release`.

I created two more because I have different headers for device and simulator build. 
[image]

I set the paths for every configuration.
[image]

Now I want to know how to set the project to run the specific configuration automatically?